How to get Zingchart base64 image on server?
I'm writing integration with Zingchart from 1C. The goal is to write http service, which recieve chart config in JSON and send back image in base64 format.
Is there a way to get base64 on the server?
I used NodeJS. But, as I understand it, it can render chart only to png or jpeg files.
(i tried to render to canvas or svg to use getimagedata method but error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'end')" occured)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

if you want to return base64, you can do this with JavaScript
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript
